# Why is Pandas DataFrame.loc different for a DataFrame with two columns as index?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am having trouble adding a row to a pandas DataFrame with two columns as index. This is the code I'm using:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'idx1', 'val'])
df = df.set_index(['id', 'idx1'])
df.loc[123, 'a'] = [1]
```

Then `df` becomes:

```
          val  a
id  idx1        
123       NaN  1
```

However, I expect to get this:

```
          val 
id  idx1        
123    a   1
```

When I change the length of the index to three (or one), I get what I expect. For example, if I run this code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'idx1', 'idx2', 'val'])
df = df.set_index(['id', 'idx1', 'idx2'])
df.loc[123, 'a', 'b'] = [1]
```

`df` becomes:

```
               val
id  idx1 idx2     
123 a    b       1
```

Is there something different when referring to two columns as index?

Comment: This is called a [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dataframe is empty. Only index and column **names** are defined. So how should Pandas know what you mean by `df.loc[123, 'a'] = 1`?

- create an entry with the first index `123` and a column `'a'`, or
- use `123` and `'a'` as two levels of a multiindex?

Solution:

```py
df.loc[(123, 'a'), 'val'] = 1
```